# Quill template bubble; tip on top of overflow : scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, quill

I'm working with `quill.js` and its amazing! I do have one thing that I cannot figure out. I have a container and will be scrollable (imagine a 600x300 window) and i set the overflow-y: scroll; but that now hides the element.

Here demo select some text on borders and its gets hidden, i want to show it or atleast for left and right sides.

`JS`

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'bubble'   // Specify theme in configuration
});
```

`CSS`

```
.container {
  margin: 55px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius:3px;
  paddding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  display:block;
}
```

***Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ptts0afd/***

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a quick hack, you can use :

```
.ql-bubble .ql-tooltip {
  left: 0% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Asked and answered on [github](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1124).

Using the bound configuration [option](http://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#bounds).